# recurrence relation with 2 variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I need to solve the following reccurence relation:
$$a(k,n)=\frac{(n-k)*a(k,n-1)+k*a(k-1,n)}{n}$$
with:
$$a(0,n)=0, a(\frac{n}{2},n)=0$$
well im sure that $a(k,n)$ is 0 for every $k,n \in N$ but i dont know how to prove it.
Thanks.

Comment: is this recurrence defined only on even naturals? the second boundary condition doesnt really hold for odd numbers

Comment: In fact you don't even need the second condition to prove that $a\equiv 0$, it all follows from the first one.

Comment: I added the second condition, its very intutuitive to understand that a=0, but i dont know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be proved using Induction on $k$ for values, $k=0,1,...n$.

Step 1: Base step $a(k,n) = 0$ for $k=0$, which is given as the boundary condition.

Step 2: Assume $a(k-1,n) = 0$ and we need to prove $a(k,n) = 0$.

$a(k,n) = \frac{(n-k)a(k,n-1) + ka(k-1,n)}{n} = \frac{(n-k)a(k,n-1)}{n} = \frac{(n-k)(n-k-1)a(k,n-2)}{n(n-1)} = ... = \frac{(n-k)(n-k-1)...(n-k-i+1)a(k,n-i)}{n(n-1)...(n-i+1)}$

Scenario 1: $k < \frac{n}{2}$

Now pick $i= n-2k > 0$ so that rightmost expression becomes a multiple of $a(k,2k)$ which is 0 according to the second boundary condition. Note that there exists a non-zero integer $i = n-2k$ under this scenario.

Scenario 2: $k = \frac{n}{2}$

In this scenario, $a(k,n) = a(\frac{n}{2},n) =0 $ as per the boundary condition.

Scenario 3: $k=n$

We can apply one-step recursion to $a(n,n)$ to see that it's 0.

Scenario 4: $n>k > \frac{n}{2}$

In this scenario, pick $i = n-k > 0$ so that rightmost expression becomes a multiple of $a(k,k)$ which is 0 from scenario 3. Similarly note that non-zero integer $i$ exists under this scenario.